# Angular Unit Testing - Cannot Find Name 'xyzDirective'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular5, karma-jasmine

I have a component that uses a module loader and when I import it to my spec file I can't seem to test a specific directive because it can't be found. I an getting

```
Cannot find name 'AwesomeHelperDirective'
```

and the Jasmine output says:

```
ReferenceError: AwesomeHelperDirective is not defined
```

**My module looks like this...**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {
  AwesomeComponent,
} from './awesome.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AwesomeComponent,
      AwesomeHelperDirective,
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [
      AwesomeComponent,
      AwesomeHelperDirective,
  ]
})
export class AwesomeModule { }
```

**In my spec file I have this:**

```
import { AwesomeModule } from './awesome.module';

describe('AwesomeComponent', () => {

   const html =  `<app-template></app-template>`;

   beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [AwesomeModule],
        declarations: [TestComponent],
      }).overrideComponent(TestComponent, {
          set: {template: html},
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    it('should ...', () => {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      const clickMock = spyOn(AwesomeHelperDirective, 'onClick');
      fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('awesome-helper')).triggerEventHandler('click', null);
      expect(clickMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Comment: You import the module (that contains the directive), but declare it again in. Remove `AwesomeHelperDirective` from the `TestBed` declarations.

Comment: I have. Same problem.

Comment: My bad I didn't see the bottom where you spy. Import the directive `import {
  AwesomeComponent,
AwesomeHelperDirective,
} from './awesome.component';`

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you!